# Ruby fixtures error with password column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, fixtures

I am trying to load a fixture for my tests which has a password column (binary datatype). The tool i am using uses EzCrypto gem for encrypting and decrypting passwords before they are stored/retrieved. Now if my column is binary i thought rails would automatically store the password as encrypted - but all i get is:

**1.**

```
Error:
 test_is_working(FirstTest):
 RuntimeError: Failed to decode the field. Incorrect key?
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mislav-will_paginate 2.3.11/lib/will_paginate/finder.rb:170:in 'method_missing'
unit/first_test.rb:8:in setup
```

**2.**

```
Error:
test_sanity(FirstTest):
RuntimeError: Failed to decode the field. Incorrect key?
    unit/first_test.rb:8:in `setup'


    Fixture file looks like this:
    first_hussle:
        type: FirstAccount
        user: jsewq
        username: abc@mac.com
        password: 'abc123'
```

any clues?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ezcrypto to encrypt the password in your fixture.  Assuming that your fixture is for the users table and that you've got a `user_crypto_provider.rb` file / class defined.

```
password: <%= UserCryptoProvider.encrypt('abc123') %>
```